# Table view not showing correctly

Tags: uitableview, swift3, uiimageview, autolayout, xcode8

I am trying to fix this for long time :(
It is an imageView in the table view 
There is no error, there is no Autolayout missing.
But the Content View on the left side is showing in Yellow

[image: Table view]

Comment: Show what you have written in your tableView delegate methods.

Comment: it is too big to insert here, how can I show?

Comment: Edit your question with necessary code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this:

in viewDidLoad():

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

OR

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
```

OR

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-65, 0, 0, 0)
```

OR

In InterfaceBuilder:

1. Select the view controller
2. Open Attributes inspector
3. There's a property called "Adjust scroll view insets" in IB's attribute inspector (when a view controller is selected) which is on by default.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I tried each one and all together but still the same :(

Comment: Pls, check my edited answer you should also try UIEdgeInsetsMake(-65, 0, 0, 0)

Comment: Sorry did not work.  I will delete and redo it from the beginning and let you know.

Comment: For some reason after start new one the table view show as expected :) Thank you for your help.